# PouchDB in multiple tab

Tags: indexeddb, pouchdb, web-sql

#### I did't get good example how to handle PouchDB in multiple tabs.

Let me describe my example:

1. Creating a local PouchDB.
2. Continously pulling an array of integers via ajax.
3. Concat with old array if present, add/update it with some id.

If we are using indexedDB, [here is a good article on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Version_changes_while_a_web_app_is_open_in_another_tab).

Is there anything like this in PouchDB?